# How to set an item selected in extjs tree panel by default?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a tree panel with some items. Whenever I render the treepanel an item should be selected by default.

Comment: Make an try first, which gives you more hope. if you fail in your code, post those code and get resolved here. Let your contribution fix it too....

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code. This will work

```
Ext.each(Nodes, function(item, index, allNodes)
{
    var rec = TreePanelObj.getView().getRecord(item);
    if() //any condition 
    {
        TreePanelObj.getSelectionModel().select(index);
    }
});
```